# How do I subtract a flat-rate healthcare cost from an inputted salary?

Tags: python, if-statement, branch, codeblocks

I am trying to calculate the net pay of a bi-weekly salary by first subtracting healthcare costs and then calculating the federal tax reduction. I understand how to calculate the tax deduction, but I don't know how to first subtract the healthcare deduction ($800 if single and $1000 if married) from the salary that is inputted prior to doing the tax deductions. This is what I have so far, but I don't know where or how to subtract the flat rate of $800(single) or $1000(married) from the original salary.

```
salary = float(input('Enter salary: '))
marital_status = input('Enter marital status M for married or S for other: ')

if marital_status is 'S':
    if salary <= 10000:
        print(salary - (salary * .05))
    elif (salary >= 10000.01) and (salary <= 50000):
        print(salary - (500 + (salary * .105)))
    elif salary > 50000:
        print(salary - (4700 + (salary * .2025)))
    
if marital_status is 'M':
    if salary <= 25000.00:
        print(salary - (salary * .625))
    elif salary <= 90000.00:
    print(salary - (500.00 + (salary * .1075)))
    elif salary > 90000:
        print(salary - (8550.00 + (salary * .225)))
```

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking...it sounds like you are asking how to subtract a number from a variable like `salary = salary - 800` (or `salary -= 800`). But your code suggest you already know how to subtract and assign to a variable. You already have branches for married and single -- subtract in those.

Comment: You ask where to perform the subtraction, but you already told us: do it first, before any of the other operations.  If you don't know how to subtract a constant from a variable, then you need to return to your tutorial materials.  Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.  You seem to have trouble with problem analysis in general, rather than with Python.  This suggests a range of needs too broad for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Don't compare values with `is`. `is` is used for object identity. So `if marital_status is 'S':` should be `if marital_status == 'S':`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you are trying to do, perhaps introducing the idea of **taxable salary** solves your problem.  Here is how you could apply it for the marital status of 'S':

```
if marital_status == 'S':

    taxable_salary = salary - 800

    if taxable_salary <= 10000:
        print(salary - (salary * .05))

    elif (taxable_salary > 10000) and (taxable_salary <= 50000):
        print(salary - (500 + (salary * .105)))

    else: # taxable_salary > 50000:
        print(salary - (4700 + (salary * .2025)))
```